# My Kmail does not load mails from gmx.de anymore

Tags: mail-server, kmail

Being on Kubuntu 14.4, my Kmail stopped loading mails from GMX.de a couple of days ago. Getting mails from WEB.de (both freemail services belong to the same company) works. I have no idea what happened to cause this. Messages can be written and successfully send. If I press the button to fetch the mails, the loading bar starts to load the mails, gets to about 3% to 4% (by now there are a LOT of mails waiting) but without actually receiving any mail. Then the bar jumps to 100%, stops loading and everything is just as if nothing had happended, including having no new mails.

When I

```
$ kontact
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before
QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
```

Kontact does not start.

PS: Could it be that a specific "bad" mail is blocking the download or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Stupid one actually: My home folder `/home/me/` (or rather the partition) was too full. Emptying it did the trick. I did not notice, because my mail is actually stored on a different partitione so that wasn't it. But Kmail was not able to write stuff regarding the downloaded mails into its meta-data storage.

If someone is able to elaborate on - where kmail stores what where - with good links or more details, I would be glad about it.